# Ionic Frame Work App Update Plugin Google Play Console suspended the app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have used Ionic Frame Work App Update Plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-update **Google Play Console has suspended the app due to network abuse policy violation**.

After making an appeal to Play Support they made me to submit the app by removing the plugin and it's usage in the app.

So why the Ionic Framework still has this plugin in their official documentation website and they should notify the developer as **it should not be used in the production app**.

Comment: sorry. the link seems to go to 404 page for me. Can you link the plugin?

Comment: It's been removed by ionic team after the intimation by me.